# What is an anchor in GridBagLayout?

Tags: java, gridbaglayout

I've looked through stackoverflow and I haven't been able to find a good explanation for an anchor in GridBagLayout. I know how to use it but when I do I'm not exactly sure what it is doing. Can someone please explain what an anchor is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

anchor is a constraint that is used to position that element at a particular location when the component is smaller than its display area. anchor can have values CENTER, NORTH, NORTHEAST, EAST, SOUTHEAST, SOUTH, SOUTHWEST, WEST, and NORTHWEST.

NOTE: anchor property won't work if your fill constraint is set to **GridBagConstraints.BOTH** as fill constraint stretches the component both horizontally and vertically covering all of the display area. Also, if you set fill to GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL then the anchor's horizontal values EAST and WEST won't work as the component has been stretched to horizontally to cover the horizontal display area. Similarly, anchor's vertical values won't work if the fill property has been set to GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL.